# How to get values from controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-studio

I am trying to print hello world. 
For that i created class and return function in models folder, and the returning value is "hello world".
In controller, i am getting the values from module like this:

```
    $value = new getValue();
    $this->view->index = $value->hello_world();
```

I don't know how to get the values from controllers and print into views php folder.

Comment: You should add some code and more details off what you did, it's currently impossible to understand anything without that. But did you even follow some tutorials or "getting started" guides ?

Comment: No i dint have any guides for zend framework. today only i started working, its tough to understand the flow of Zend framework. do you have any guidance.

Comment: you need to go through "Zend Framework Conventions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fac, you put "Hello world" string into the variable "index" of the controller's view when your are doing this `$this->view->index = $value->hello_world();`.

So, if your `$value->hello_world();` function correctly return an "Hello world" string, for print it into the controller's view, you just have to do add this php code `echo $this->index;` into your view file.

Comment: 'echo $this-> index;' this is my printing statement in view. when i compile the page is blank..

Comment: Are you sure of your Zend project structure ?
can you details more of your code and the structure of your project ?

Comment: I am not familiar with zend framework. This is the first application i started to understand the flow of the framework.

Comment: @HariRam : Into your project, you should have "views/scripts/" folder wich contains a folder named like your controller (if you have an "HelloController", you have a "hello" folder wich contains all your "HelloController" views).  
And For the action into your controller "displayAction", you have a "display.phtml" file.  
In this file, you have to put your "echo" instruction.  
Try http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html for more explainations.

Comment: if you have any sample program, can you pls share to me. i just want to know the flow of zend framework.

Comment: @HariRam : see the dinopmi answer. Take time to discover Zend Framework, it's a great tool but if you don't know how to user it, you will duplicate code and doing conception mistake. (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should read a tutorial first of all. It can be quite hard to try to figure out how Zend Framework works just by starting to code right away.

- The [Quick Start guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) suggested by @palmplam should be fine.
- In addition, I found the [Rob Allen's tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) really useful when I started using Zend Framework. It contains plenty of sample code.